# Is there a way to get the current capacity of a HashSet?

Tags: .net

Maybe I'm just missing something, but the HashSet(Of T) class has as TrimExcess method, but no publicly accessible way of finding out the current capacity of an instance. Is there some way I'm being too dense to find?

Comment: It's not public, so it'd take some reflection magic to dig it out. Just curious, why would you want to know?

Comment: @kbrimington: Mostly out of curiosity, really. List(Of T) has a public property for getting Capacity, so I thought it was strange that HashSet doesn't.

Comment: @rossisdead: Fair enough. I've never needed it before... Perhaps MS decided it wasn't necessary. HashSet, after all, was added in .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the capacity can be gotten from the length of the private member m_buckets. You can view its value during Debug. To access private members during runtime you can use either Reflection or dynamics in .NET 4.0.